# Change opencart logo in order email

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to change my logo in order email, because my theme needs some white color that not shown in email, I know how to change the logo but i want to change specifically my email logo without change the main one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the logo in

```
//catalog/model/checkout/order.php:441
$data['logo'] = $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
```

or  in

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl:8
```

change the image source